# How to JOIN information from two different tables using SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to return data from two different tables and also filter out some of the data from being returned. I have a publisher table and an author table.
I am getting an error:

MySQL No: 1064
MySQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IL' AND p.state = 'IL' ORDER BY p.name, p.city, a.name, a.city, a.state' at line 4
SQL: SELECT p.name, p.city, a.name, a.city, a.state FROM publisher p JOIN author a ON (p.state= a.state) WHERE a.city = 'Chicago AND a.state = 'IL' AND p.state = 'IL' ORDER BY p.name, p.city, a.name, a.city, a.state
MySQL Affected Rows: -1

SQL

```
 SELECT p.name, p.city, a.name, a.city, a.state
FROM publisher p JOIN author a
            ON (p.state= a.state)
WHERE  a.city = 'Chicago' AND a.state = 'IL' AND  p.state = 'IL'
ORDER BY  p.name, p.city, a.name, a.city, a.state;
```

Comment: what error did you get when you execute this query as query looks correct to me?

Comment: That looks good, you could change the id to 
AND P.pub_ID IN (1, 3)  other then that looks fine

Comment: Thank you Brad. I was thinking there was a shorter or better way of writing the same statement. I appreciate the input.

Comment: Rajen, No error just thought there was a more efficient way to write the same statement so it is not so lengthy.

Comment: Hey guys, can I have some input on the above statement? This is a statement in which I am receiving an error. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Your error shows you're missing a quote after Chicago, but your sample query isn't.  Next time, post your actual query and error first instead of editing them in afterwards or trying to generate a similar one.

Comment: @Devon Okay, thank you Devon.

Answer (score 0):

joining on state it's not necessary to do a.state = 'IL' AND  p.state = 'IL'.
Try to do something like this:

```
SELECT P.NAME, P.CITY, A.NAME, A.CITY, A.STATE
FROM PUBLISHER P, AUTHOR A
WHERE A.STATE = P.STATE 
AND A.CITY = "Chicago"
AND A.STATE = "IL"
ORDER BY P.NAME, P.CITY, A.NAME, A.CITY, A.STATE
```

Comment: Hey GJCode! Thanks for the input. A couple of things: 1) I need to return a city for the author and the same State for the author AND the publisher. Does your answer meet that criteria? Also, without using JOIN how does SQL know to combine the 2 tables data as I do not see any form of JOIN in your answer? Thank you in advance!

Comment: 1) yes this match your criteria, this query returns only tuples that have Chicago as author city and state "IL" both for the author and the publisher, this due the join beacause if you say that the state of the author must be equal to the state of publisher and the state of author must be "IL" you will have "IL" both for the author and the publisher. @TRS7

Comment: 2) the join condition is a.state = p.state, this is a natural join, there is a module called optimizer in a dbms (not all dbms have that) that translate what you write in an internal representation of the query. I never use Join on condition, not in Oracle, MySql, PostgresSQL and school :) and this works, if you write Join On the optimizer does what I do. @TRS7